# how to store minute fraction part of latitude into 4 unsigned char in c++

Tags: c++, integer, latitude-longitude, shift, unsigned-char

i have latitude value in string format and i want to store mmmmm part of dd mm.mmmmm latitude into 4 unsigned char value. and then want to perform some shift operations..

my code is :

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char latitude[11]="",temp[5]; unsigned char byt[4];int deg,min;
strcpy(latitude,"1234.99999N");
strncpy(temp,latitude,2);
deg = atoi(temp);
strcpy(temp,"");
strncpy(temp,latitude+2,2);
min = atoi(temp);
strcpy(temp,"");
strncpy(temp,latitude+5,5);
int min_frac_part = atoi(temp);
cout<<"minfrac : "<<min_frac_part<<"\n";
byt[3] = (min_frac_part >> 24) & 0xFF;
byt[2] = (min_frac_part >> 16) & 0xFF;
byt[1] = (min_frac_part >> 8) & 0xFF;
byt[0] = (min_frac_part) & 0xFF;

unsigned char input[2];
input[0] = (byt[1] << 2);
cout<<"input[0] is : "<<input[0]<<"\n";



   return 0;
}
```

this input[0] is not proper.. so i am not able to assign this int value to 4 unsigned char values.. also this byt values are passed to another function as unsigned char..

Comment: What does "this input[0] is not proper" mean?

Comment: `deg = atoi(temp);` reads out of bounds , `atoi` expects a null-terminted string, but you never null-terminated `temp`. You make this same error several times in the code

Answer (score 0):

1. `latitude` needs to be 12 characters long instead of 11, as [`strcpy()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy) also puts a terminating zero character at the very end, which is out of array bounds when the string constant you copy there is 11 characters long.
2. [`strncpy()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strncpy), in its turn, does not add a terminating zero at the end, unless it is among the characters copied. This leads to undefined behaviour, since there may be anything at `temp[2]`, `temp[3]` and `temp[4]`, including other numbers. `temp[2]` has to be `'\0'` before `atoi()` is called for the first time.
3. There are several places where such errors are present.